# Owner object that takes pre-created values ? Wrong design?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, raii, ownership

It is a wrong design to have an object that is considered as the **owner of it's components** (or items in the case of an array / map) but that only deletes them and **doesn't construct them** ?

For example if I have a hierarchy of classes :

```
class A { public: virtual ~A() { } };
class A1 : public A { };
class A2 : public A { };
```

And if need to store several instances of A1 and/or A2 into a same array and using polymorphism (i.e `vector< A * >`), is it a correct design to create a class that encapsulates the vector to delete the elements ?

```
class ArrayOfA
{
private:
    std::vector< A * > m_items;
public:
    ~ArrayOfA() { for( auto a : m_items ) delete a; }
    void add( A * a ) { m_items.push_back( a ); }
};
```

Which is then used as follows :

```
ArrayOfA arr;
arr.add( new A1() );
arr.add( new A2() );
throw; // Do not care about release for RAII
```

The problem is if someone adds an A that is owned by something else. But this should not be a problem if it is clearly stated in the documentation that ArrayOfA will delete it. But for some reason it feels like this design is flawn.

I know that it is possible using C++11 to use variadic templates to pass the parameters of the constructors of A1 or A2 to ArrayOfA::add() so that the object makes both the new and the delete, but I don't want to use that.

Comment: Use a shared_ptr or unique_ptr instead: `arr.add(std::make_shared<A1>() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Read the question. You do not need a special container class. You need a vector of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks. What about C++<11 ?

Comment: About C++ < 11, use std::shared_ptr, or write your own smart pointer.

Comment: Pre-C++11 you do not have auto, which is protruding from your code.

Comment: @AntonTodua, `auto_ptr`? In `std::vector`? You are unbelievable.

Comment: I know that auto is C++11. What i'm asking is what to do when using C++<11 ? Is the only option to create a unique ptr ?

Comment: Like suggested above, you can use `shared_ptr` from boost - though I am not in love with those.

Comment: So i'm going to go for unique ptrs. In this case what would my add function look like ? I've just read about move semantics but i'm not very comfortable with that yet. For `vector< unique_ptr< A > >` I would have `void add( unique_ptr< A > uptr_a ) { m_items.push_back( move( uptr_a) ); }` ? And should i pass the `unique_ptr` by reference ? Thanks.

Comment: @Virus721, go for it! :) (always prefix std functions with std, though - so `std::move(...)` You might want to consider passing unique_ptr<A> by reference (gives a slight performance edge), but passing by value makes the ownership clear, so I'd suggest the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ownership is exactly that. i.e the responsibility to delete an object. It does not imply or even encourage that the owning entity create the owned entity.

It is absolutely ok for the creation to take place somewhere else as long as ownership is passed in an obvious way.

For C++, use

```
std::<unique_ptr>
```

rather than documentation to make this explicit. It will also allow your code to do automatic cleanup.

use

```
std::<shared_ptr>
```

when the ownership is not clear. i.e it is not deterministic or clear which entity should end up actually deleting the object.

For more information read about smart pointers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.